# AngularJS component doesn't load dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I have the next notation in my app.js file:

```
state = {
                        component: item.component,
                        url: item.url,
                        resolve: {
                            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                                if (item.deps) {
                                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(item.deps);                                    
                                }
                            }]
                        }                        
                    };  `
```

The item.component contains the (Angular 1.5) component's name, while the container file should be lazy loaded using $ocLazyLoad. Nevertheless unknown provider error is thrown even before dependencies are loaded. I'm using the 1.0.0 ui-router, which should allow using components in routings.